# State managment in flutter with consumer and scaffoldState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using the Provider dependencie to manage states on my screen. Currently I have created a Loading Screen that works with Lottie animation. In my Sign In page, whenever there is an error with the log in, a Snackbar is shown to the user. Althought now, when I use the splash screen, the screen doesn't return and the snackBar isn't shown.

 This is a piece of the login screen:

```
Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    onPressed: userManager.loading
                                        ? null
                                        : () {
                                            if (formKey.currentState!
                                                .validate()) {
                                              userManager.signIn(
                                                  user: User(
                                                      email:
                                                          emailController.text,
                                                      password:
                                                          passController.text),
                                                  onFail: (e) {
                                                    scaffoldKey.currentState!
                                                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                      content: Text(
                                                          'Falha ao entrar: $e'),
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Colors.red,
                                                    ));
                                                  },
                                                  onSucess: () {
                                                    debugPrint(
                                                        'Sucesso ao Logar');
                                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                  });
                                            }
                                          },
```

On the onFail I get this error, whenever I have a wrong password or other datas wrong:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

This is how I'm changing between pages:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UserManager>(builder: (_, userManager, child) {
      if (userManager.loading) {
        return SplashScreen();
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
```

UserManager:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/helpers/firebase_errors.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user.dart';

class UserManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserManager() {
    _loadCurrentUser();
  }

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User? user;

  bool _loading = false;
  bool get loading => _loading;
  bool get isLoggedIn => user != null;

  Future<void> signIn(
      {required User user,
      required Function onFail,
      required Function onSucess}) async {
    loading = true;
    try {
      final AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: user.email!, password: user.password!);

      await _loadCurrentUser(firebaseUser: result.user);

      onSucess();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      onFail(getErrorString(e.code));
    }
    loading = false;
   notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> signUp(
      {required User user,
      required Function onFail,
      required Function onSucess}) async {
    loading = true;
    try {
      final AuthResult result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: user.email!, password: user.password!);

      user.id = result.user.uid;
      this.user = user;

      await user.saveData();

      onSucess();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      onFail(getErrorString(e.code));
    }
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
    user = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set loading(bool value) {
    _loading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCurrentUser({FirebaseUser? firebaseUser}) async {
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseUser ?? await auth.currentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
      final DocumentSnapshot docUser = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(currentUser.uid)
          .get();
      user = User.fromDocument(docUser);

      final docAdmin = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('admins')
          .document(user!.id!)
          .get();
      if (docAdmin.exists) {
        user!.admin = true;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  bool get adminEnabled => user != null && user!.admin;
}
```

Is there another way to set the splash screen thats easier?

Comment: can you share the `UserManager` class, too?

Comment: @venir Sure, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wait for you to add the `UserManager` class implementation, I think there's a missing `notifyListeners()` in the `signIn` method.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunatly, I have added a notifyListeners() under the loading = false

Comment: Well, it looks like there's a `notifyListener()` missing in `UserManager` 's `signIn` method.. or is this a copy-paste mistake? I can see the `notifyListener()` under the `signUp()` method for example.

Comment: It was a copy paste mistake, I have updated the question

Comment: You set `loading` to `true` inside `logIn` and `signIn`, without calling `notifyListener()`. This causes the UI not to reload (you call it only when you're done). I'll give a more complete answer tomorrow

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, isn't the problem the `scaffoldKey.currentState`? When the screen changes the snackBar has problems being called

Comment: Why are you calling the `snackBar` with the `scaffoldKey`? Didn't `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);` work?

Comment: I will attempt so, what is the difference between? Do you think that's the error?

Comment: It worked fine ussing scaffoldMessager, could't you formulate a answer explaining the difference please, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm happy it worked: upvote my question if it did. Personally I never use `scaffoldKey`, I actually don't even know what it is. I always refer to the `ScaffoldMessenger` to pass messages onto that.